# PHP MYSQL Question on comparing dates in a Query

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to construct a mysql query string to pull out certain records but only if the date in the database is greater than the current date.

So I have this so far and I am not sure if this is a legal syntax...

```
date_default_timezone_set('America/Los_Angeles');
$current_date = date("Y-m-d");

$sql = "SELECT * FROM `coupons` WHERE status = 1 AND end_date > '$current_date'";
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Yes, this is legal syntax. Why not trying yourself ? :)

Comment: +1 to arnaud. When it comes to syntax, isn't it a lot faster and easier to simply try if the statement works instead of posting a question and waiting for an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's legal syntax. You can use one.

Answer (score 0):

I use `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` in general, i.e.:

```
SELECT * FROM `coupons` WHERE status = 1 AND end_date > CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

Do you have a need to compare to the LA timezone? `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` will use the local MySQL server time (but that should technically be what the date values are stored as, as well).

Comment: The reason why I don't use current_timestamp is because my hosting server isn't in the same timezone as me locally...Not sure if they allow me to set that otherwise...